# How to see all the queries being executed in php MySQl?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My system uses php + MySQL and I don't want to track file by file, function by function to find all the queries being executed.

Is there an easier way to find all the queries being executed like debug bar from laravel ?

Comment: 2 cloeses, 1 downvote and 0 explanations why =) Amazing !

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. As the description of such flag indicates: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question._ That link is very important. I haven't voted in this question yet. Btw, not only people are free to vote as they please, but not all _interesting_ questions _fit_ in StackOverflow.

Comment: To my understanding, this question could also be close as: off-topic -> _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: All that I could find about this kind of track was Tracking `errors`. My system has no erros so far, I just want to know the queries used/executed. Also, as its tagged as `php` and `html`, plus comparing ti `debug bar` I don't see how I could be asking anything other than some kind of code/pluging/etc, but ok.
And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: are you talking about something which would walk through your source code to find where in the code queries get triggered from, or are you talking about logging each actual query which gets executed during usage?

Comment: I'll use Laravel Debugbar as example: If you load a page, it shows you all the queries executed on that page. The raw sql (`e.g: select * from ...`).  I just need to find that.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal application this would be done using decorator, which you would wrap around your DB abstraction (like PDO or MySQLi) and then using this decorator to replace the the previously defined dependency in the DI container's configuration.

But since you are using Laravel, there is an option to add listener for all DB activity.
[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#listening-for-query-events).

Basically, if you want to see that information in the debug bar, the code would end up looking something like this:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    Debugbar::info($query);
});
```

---

With both of these options, you would have the same problem - you would only see the queries, that get called on the executions path, that you yourself accessed.

To get the a complete list of called queries, you would have to have a setup of "integrations tests" (for lack of better name), which have a 100% code coverage. Then you could use one of the previously described approaches and collect logs about **all** queries that are actually executed.

Comment: Guess I made some mistake trying to explain my situation, sorry about that. I'm not actually using Laravel. This project is using `php` only, no frameworks... I Just used laravel's debug bar as an example. It shows you easily all the queries executed and thats What I need.